# Vectors and set theory

Tags: geometry, elementary-set-theory, vectors

How does one see a vector through the lens of set theory? As just the end point? Or the set of points on the segment between the starting point and ending point of the vector? Or just the start point and end point?

Example:

Let $$\vec v=\langle x_1,x_2,x_3\rangle$$
start at the origin and end at $p=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$.

Then $s=\{(x_1t,x_2t,x_3t)|t\in[0,1]\}$ is the segment between the origin and $p$.

And thus if $|s|$ denotes the length of $s$, then $|s|=|\vec v|$.

But in terms of a set, what would $\vec v$ be? Would there be use to this sort of definition?

Comment: It's none of those things. Vectors do not have start points and end points. A vector can describe the relative position of two points, but lots of points have the exact same positions relative to each other, and the same vector applies equally to all such pairs, and not to any pair of points in particular.

Comment: @DavidK Okay. That clears some things up, but I still have questions. Are there any advantages to treating vectors as segments? What's the difference between a vector and a directed segment?

Comment: A reminder that vector spaces do not necessarily need a useful geometry or even topology through which you can view them.  The set of all continuous functions for example is a vector space, the vectors in this case being the functions themselves.  Heck, if you could find an appropriate context and definitions for addition and scalar multiplication your vector space could consist of the set of the most popular baby names of 2018.  Thinking of vectors only as "arrows of a certain length in a certain direction" is focusing too heavily on narrow applications and is ignoring the general definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the point of view of set theory, a vector in a finite dimensional vector space is simply an ordered $n$-tuple: for example
$$
\begin{split}
  \vec v=(x_1,x_2)\triangleq\{\{x_1\},\{x_1,x_2\}\}&\qquad n=2\\
  \vec v=(x_1,x_2,x_3)\triangleq(x_1,(x_2,x_3))&\qquad n=3
\end{split}
$$
and so on (i.e. proceeding by induction), one gets the set theoretical structure of a vector: everything else, from the multiplication by scalars to the concept of space points, comes if you add further "structure" to the set of vectors so obtained.

Comment: It's not even necessarily an $n$-tuple; that's just the easiest way to make a vector spaces out of a field, but there are a lot of vector spaces with vectors that don't look much like that. The only thing one can say about a vector generally is that it's an element of a vector space.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine: yes, you're right. Vectors are simply point sets which satisfy the axioms of vector space structure. However, the example(s) given seem show that the OP is mainly interested on finite dimensional vector spaces: this is the main reason for which I gave the answer above.